# Do absolutely continuous random variables have a continuous distribution function

Tags: probability

If we define absolutely continuous random variables by Lebesgue integrals & Lebuesgue measures, i.e.

$$F(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} f(x) d x$$

for some Lebesgue integrable $f(x)\ge 0$, is it always the case that $F$ is continuous? I know this is true for Riemann integrals due to the fundamental theorem of calculus. Forgive me if this is a stupid question, I'm doing a probability course with very little measure theory in it.

Comment: Let's see:
$$
  |F(t+\epsilon) - F(t)| = \left|\int_t^{t+\epsilon} f(x)\,dx \right| =\int_t^{t+\epsilon} f(x)\,dx
$$
... do you expect this to go to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: @cfh well it's upper bounded by $sup_{t\le x \le t+\epsilon} f(x)$ so yes?

Comment: But do you know that the supremum is finite for any $\epsilon$?

Comment: @cfh Not really so I guess that argument doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can say more: that $F(t)$ is *absolutely continuous*. See Wikipedia articles (or the relevant sections of a measure theory book) on [absolute continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) and the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem).